# Conflicting jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this conflict but I can not find the reason. When I remove jquery-1.6.1.min the download button works correctly. But fancybox stops working for lack of jQuery library. I have already used jQuery.noConflict but it did not work.

No jQuery working: http://www.sitelab.combr.co/curso-js/
With jQuery working: http://www.sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/

The conflict seems to be with these two scripts:
sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/js-spa.js
sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/sp212.js

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js desktop">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000">
  <title>Menu Clone</title>

  <!-- ESTILO -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/style.css">

  <!-- SCRIPT'S -->
  <script src="//sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/js-spa.js"></script>

  <!--<script src="./js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
  <script src="//sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    successCallback = function(q){
      if(q == 'false'){
        $('#waitenyo').html('');
        $('#waitenyo').removeClass('waitenyo');
        $('#waitenyo').addClass('erroenyo');
      }else{
        $('#waitenyo').removeClass('waitenyo');
        $('#waitenyo').addClass('successenyo');
        $('#waitenyo').html('<a id="facyok" target="_blank" href="'+q+'"></a>');
      }
    }
    makedown = function(a){
      var link = $(this).attr('alt');
      $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'content'       : '<div class="waitenyo" id="waitenyo"><img src="images/load.gif"></div>',
        'title'         : false,
        'hideOnContentClick':false,
        'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
        'autoDimensions':true,
        'centerOnScroll':true,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'showCloseButton': true
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?q2='+link,
        success: successCallback
      });

    }

    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.downlink').each(function(){
        $(this).bind('click',makedown);
      });
    })

  </script>

</head>  

<body onunload="" class="module-release page-release action-watch user-full type-scene">
  <div class="page-wrapper">

    <main class="js-content-top">
      <section class="section section--dark">
        <div class="l-container-player">
          <div id="player-container" class="player-wrapper">
            <div class="player">
              <div class="player-panel js-video-download">
                <div class="player-panel__group">
                  <div class="player-panel__group-title"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Cursos</div>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>HD MP4 1080P</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>HD MP4 720P</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>SD MP4</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>MPEG4</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>MOBILE HIGH</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>MOBILE MEDIUM</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="downlink" id="downlink" alt="cursos1.zip">
                    <span>MOBILE LOW</span>
                    <span></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="player-panel js-video-settings" id="video-setting">
                <div class="player-panel__group">
                  <div class="player-panel__group-title"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Video Quality</div>
                  <a href="javascript:;"
                    data-format="1080"
                    data-storage="video-format[1080]"
                    title="FULL HD Quality">
                    <span>FULL HD</span>
                    <span>1080P</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="javascript:;"
                    data-format="3000"
                    data-storage="video-format[3000]"
                    title="HD Quality">
                    <span>HD</span>
                    <span>720P</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="javascript:;"
                    data-format="1500"
                    data-storage="video-format[1500]"
                    title="SD HIGH Quality">
                    <span>SD HIGH</span>
                    <span>480P</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="javascript:;"
                    data-format="800"
                    data-storage="video-format[800]"
                    title="SD LOW Quality">
                    <span>SD LOW</span>
                    <span>360P</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>            
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="player-section">
            <div class="player-actions">
              <div class="player-actions__group float-right">
                <a class="btn btn--medium btn--reversed js-player-panel-download-btn" href="#" title="Download">
                  <i class="fa fa-download"></i> 
                  <span class="btn__label hidden-small-down">Download Cursos</span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn--medium btn--reversed js-player-panel-settings-btn" href="#" title="Settings">
                  <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> 
                  <span class="btn__label hidden-small-down">Settings</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <!-- END SCRIPT'S -->
    <script src="//sitelab.combr.co/curso-nojs/sp212.js"></script>
   <!-- // END SCRIPT'S -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about try to update your libraries first? jquery 1.6.x is outdated, try to use 1.12.x as minimum if you need ie8 support otherwise 2.x or 3.x if you don't need ie8 support

Comment: and probably a more current version of fancybox available to match